# Should I pass a list of menu items from every control action to a view or should I pull the list?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a layout with an extension method that takes a list of menu items and creates HTML from that. In the controller actions I have:

```
public ActionResult Article(string rk)
        {
            Viewbag.menuItems = _menu.MenuItems("00");
            ..
            return View(vm);
        }
```

I have this repeated in many actions. Then in the _layout I have:

```
Html.NavLinks(ViewBag.menuItems)
```

I realize we're supposed to give the view what's needed but in this case would it be better if the view pulled partial details from an action? I'm asking this because I have only ONE layout that needs the data and I thought it may be better to code there rather than have the data retrieved in 20+ actions and sent to the views.

If it did a pull from the layout then would MVC cache the results of the action?

If pulling results from an action was better then how exactly could I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If it did a pull from the layout then would MVC cache the results of the action?

It wouldn't cache the results of the action no, it would go and get them on **every** request.

> If pulling results from an action was better then how exactly could I do it?

Instead of "pulling them from an action", just put them in the model that you are sending back from the controller, then you can use them in your view.

Comment: Regarding your comment to put them in the model. My concern there is that many actions would need to have code to get menu data. If n the layout would it not be easier as I would just have a few lines of code in one place?

Comment: Ah okay, then yeah in the _Layout and situated in the ViewBag is your best bet if your menu is on every page, that's how we do our navigation menu at work :)